# Subtract by diagonal in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Here is my data frame:

```
ID  max_t       min_t       diff
1.9 84904814    84904755    NA  
1.4 84905065    84905014    -310    
1.6 84905290    84905248    -276    
1.0 84906383    84906316    -1135   
2.9 82023344    82023251    2882972 
2.4 82023527    82023419    -276    
2.6 82023669    82023561    -250    
2.0 82023811    82023728    -250
```

My problem is with diff column.

What I want it to check the range/timediff as follows:

```
1.4 min_t - 1.9 max_t (84905014-84904814)
1.6 min_t - 1.4 max_t (84905248-84905065)
```

....

Expected output:

```
   ID    max_t    min_t     diff
1 1.9 84904814 84904755      200
2 1.4 84905065 84905014      183
3 1.6 84905290 84905248     1026
4 1.0 84906383 84906316 -2883132
5 2.9 82023344 82023251       75
6 2.4 82023527 82023419       34
7 2.6 82023669 82023561       59
8 2.0 82023811 82023728       NA
```

Here is what I have done but it didn't provide me with what I wanted.
Please advise what I miss here?

```
test$diff <- lag(test$min_t, 1) - test$max_t
```

Comment: Sure @useR I did it

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"it didn't provide me with what I wanted"_? What did you get with that code?

Comment: @useR you can see it in my question it shouldn't be -310, it should be 200.
And so on. I think maybe melting will help.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Next time, it's better to provide your expected output so others can compare their answers to your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `lead` instead of `lag`:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(lag_min_t = lag(min_t), # For demo
         lead_min_t = lead(min_t), # For demo
         diff = lead(min_t) - max_t)
```

**Result:**

```
   ID    max_t    min_t     diff lag_min_t lead_min_t
1 1.9 84904814 84904755      200        NA   84905014
2 1.4 84905065 84905014      183  84904755   84905248
3 1.6 84905290 84905248     1026  84905014   84906316
4 1.0 84906383 84906316 -2883132  84905248   82023251
5 2.9 82023344 82023251       75  84906316   82023419
6 2.4 82023527 82023419       34  82023251   82023561
7 2.6 82023669 82023561       59  82023419   82023728
8 2.0 82023811 82023728       NA  82023561         NA
```

Comment: Bravo! Thanks! Solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I see it. I think your problem is that lag does not move forward in time but backward. In your case, lag(test$min_t,1) does not start at 1.9min_t, but one before, which doesn't exist. It is also causing your operation to be backwards (diff is actually 1.4max_t - 1.9min_t), which is the inverse of what you wanted?

Instead of using lag, you could just subtract the vectors at different places and add an NA at the start of the vector:

```
    test$diff <- c(NA,min_t[-1] - max_t[-length(max_t)])
```